# React Native Expo Deploy with Distribution Push Notifications to store

Tags: react-native, expo

In a development environment my push notifications work for iOS and Android. But when I let expo handle the iOS build it does not work in testflight eventually. I think Expo gives my app a wrong certificate or a push notification certificate that is only meant for development.

What to do?

I tried to handle all the certificates myself but it didn't build eventually..

Answer (score 0):

Okay i fixed it, I had to create a Push notification Service at the certificate tab myself before I let expo handle all the building.

Hope it helps anyone